# Identify horror movie taking place in a psychiatric hospital

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

I tried googling this movie but couldn't find it out.

I saw it originally around 2007 if I recall correctly, it's a horror movie taking place in a psychiatric hospital. The plot starts when a new male psychiatrist arrives (he was white and I think he had a beard). Along the movie some of the patients and staff members are murdered, there are various suspects and also there's some kind of basement where the most dangerous patients are locked. In the end it turns out the psychiatrist was fake and was the murderer all along...

Does anybody know which movie this is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be [Madhouse (2004 film)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madhouse_%282004_film%29). It matches your description. In the movie main protagonist is an psychiatric intern comes to Madhouse where mysterious murders take place and has an unexpected twisted ending as psychiatric intern turns out to be a split-personality-disordered person with a killer second personality. Movie also has some cell for the most dangerous psychopaths. I don't remember whether the cell is in the basement or not but is too dark. The male lead has a beard too.

[image]

Comment: @darkajax you are all welcome.

Comment: Yes. It's Madhouse.
The mental hospital have the high-security ward in the basement. In the high-security ward there is a cannibal who would viciously lick and sniff the window of his cell, an old lady who killed some children she was babysitting with an overdose of medicine (the dosage was 1 tablespoon per child but she gave them 9 tablespoons per child because she had this OCD were she HAD to do everything in multiples of 9), a guy who was obsessed with women and an empty cell (this is the cell that housed the main character when he was institutionalized there during his childhood, he scaped